# Display choices based on click

Tags: html

With jquery I want to display the selected category.If I click on the line Cat 1 id="categories" I want one that is displayed in the top class ="itemLinks", idem if I select Cat 2

```
<div id="content">
    <p class="itemLinks" data-category="categories-1">Cat 1</p>
</div>
<div id="categories">
        <div data-target_category="categories-1" class="categoryItems">Cat 1</div>
        <div data-target_category="categories-2" class="categoryItems">Cat 2</div>
        <div data-target_category="categories-3" class="categoryItems">Cat 3</div>
        <div data-target_category="categories-4" class="categoryItems">Cat 4</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tatane/uxL1u831/2/
How to do ?

Comment: Unclear to me, please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Hoping I understood your question, you can try to do it like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/wa00Lcc7/1/);

**HTML:**

```
<div id="content">
    <p class="itemLinks" data-category="categories-1">Cat 1</p>
</div>
<div id="categories">
    <div data-target_category="categories-1" class="categoryItems">Cat 1</div>
    <div data-target_category="categories-2" class="categoryItems">Cat 2</div>
    <div data-target_category="categories-3" class="categoryItems">Cat 3</div>
    <div data-target_category="categories-4" class="categoryItems">Cat 4</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.categoryItems').click(function(){
    var category = $(this).text();
    $('.itemLinks').text(category);
});
```

***Do not forget to include jQuery***

What happens here is when you click on a `<div>` with the `class="categoryItems"` attribute, the text in your `<p class="itemLinks">` changes to the text in the div you have clicked.

Hope I helped!

Comment: @user3831928 No problem! please do not forget to mark this as the correct answer so people with the same problem can quickly find the right answer

Comment: @user3831928 the jsfiddle you included opens an empty fiddle, update the link and I will see what I can do

Comment: I will ask you once again for your help. Look at this page https://jsfiddle.net/tatane/wvoLr6r2/, click on "Toutes catégories"

What I want is that when you click on Cat 2 the text is in <div id = "catcherch">Toutes catégories</ div> is modified by <div id = "catcherch"> Cat 2 </ div>

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but do you mean the same as in the question before but this time, it changes the text in the `<div id="catcherch">` ? @user3831928

Comment: You can just change the  `$('.itemLinks').text(category);` to `$('#catcherch').text(category);` and it will change this, If you want them both to change just add the `$('#catcherch').text(category);` to the `$('.categoryItems').click(function(){` and it will do what you want it to do @user3831928

Comment: @user3831928 is that what you meant?

Comment: Very nice and why close the toggle when clicked to C1? https://jsfiddle.net/tatane/wvoLr6r2/3/

Comment: that's because of   `$("#catcherch").click(function(){
        $("#catsearchb").toggle();
    });` @user3831928

Comment: sorry but I do not understand your answer

Comment: Your categories are toggled by clicking on   `$("#catcherch").click(function(){
        $("#catsearchb").toggle();
    });` so if you change the text, it will still close it due to that bit of code. @user3831928

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hm6o39ze/2/ I edited the code and result to explain what happens @user3831928

Comment: @user3831928 Does that clarify it?

Comment: Look the image that's what I want http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/706681img.png

Comment: [Updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y08k9txd/) to work as specified in the image @user3831928

Comment: ok but if click in Cat2 it does not disappear! The block should disappear when you click on CAT 1 CAT 2 or CAT 3, you know?

Comment: In #catsearchb ,  If I click on CAT 1  #catsearchb,  #catsearchb must disappear And there must be marked CAT 1in  #catcherch.etc,You know ?

Comment: No problem, Like I've said before, please consider marking this answer as the correct answer so other people can quickly find the answer if they encounter the same problem. @user3831928